# Filter dates from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, momentjs

I have used AWS Comprehend service to extract entities from the document text and I have an array of date entities with various formats which looks like this:

```
const dateArr = [
  "25.11.2021", "10. Juli 2005", "30/03/2011", "20 years ago", "22.01.2012/yrs", "03.09.2019", "09.09.2019"
];
```

The goal is to format all dates to be in the same format and get the most recent date with moment.js:

```
const possibleFormats = [
    'DD MMMM YYYY', 'DD.MM.YY', 'DD.MM.YYYY', 'DD/MM/YYYY'
];
const locale = 'de';
const result = dateArr.map(el => {
    return moment(el, possibleFormats, locale)
});
const mostRecentDate = moment.max(result).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
```

but after running this code, it will recognize this date entity `20 years ago` as the 20th of the current month and year and it will be the most recent date.

I tried to filter the array like this:

```
const validDates = dateArr.filter(date => new Date(date) != 'Invalid Date')
```

then, it will treat `25.11.2021` as an invalid date because `new Date()` constructor's default format is MM/DD/YYYY (if I'm not mistaken).

And I tried with moment.js strict parameter but it ignores `10. Juli 2005` and `22.01.2012/yrs`:

```
moment(el, possibleFormats, locale, true)
```

How can I filter this array to remove only date entities like this one `20 years ago`? Or should I do something else?

Thanks!

Comment: how about add this filter ` if (date.indexOf('years ago') !== -1) { return false }` to filter dates that contain that string.

Comment: @Nilebac this array is just let example how it can look like. It could contain different string in different language also.

Comment: You have an awkward problem to solve because NLP can annotate a string as a 'date' and that string has an infinite list of possibilities, e.g.  'Last QTR', '3 yrs ago', 'prior summer', 'the 3rd day of the fourth month  1979'. Thats before you consider languages.

You are limited by your NLP and what the java libraries (Date, Period, Moment) are designed to read, unless you sub-class them or build a pre-processor that translates the available formats.  You may want to consider tidying up the text first, using regex to extract recognisable formats, numbers or months; or teach your own NLP :-)

Comment: You can have a look at [chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono), although number of languages it supports is limited.